# Finding ratio objects/key which Counting sort worst case faster than Quicksort worst case

Tags: algorithm, quicksort, counting-sort

I have a question which I am trying to solve for personal understanding of comparing algorithms as follows. I am given  n to be the number of objects and m be the number of keys. I want to find the ratios objects/keys (m/n) that CountingSort is faster in the worst case compared to QuickSort when quicksort chooses the last element as the pivot. 
So I have that the worst case running time for CountingSort is O(n+k) and the case when quicksort chooses the last element as the pivot is Theta(n^2). I'm confused of how to approach this question and would welcome some guidance so I could reach a solution.

My idea is that it will be for when the number of keys is double the number of objects? So we have that the runtime for worst case of quicksort is O(n^2) so we want to have counting sort less than this. Therefore if we have rations of m/n < m^2/n this will be the case?

Comment: The worst case of quick sort is O(n^2) if we somehow always choose the smallest or biggest number as the pivot. Can you specify your question a little bit more?

Comment: So my goal is to find for which ratios objects(n)/keys(m) is CountingSort in its worst case faster than Quicksort when the biggest number is chosen as the pivot.

Comment: You can't use bigO for this. You have to calculate exact numbers of comparisons (assuming "faster" means "fewest comparisons", rather than "fewest swaps" or some other metric).

Comment: So it will be a more trial and error proof rather than an actual proof with O(n). I'll have to find when an array of length n takes longer to sort by QuickSort than the worst case of countingSort

Comment: Well, counting sort doesn't rely on comparison.You could run both alg. on big sets and time them.